# Font awesome icons don't work

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm having a problem with [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/). In the following jsfiddle you can see that I am getting some really weird character instead of a bluetooth icon

https://jsfiddle.net/petarvasilev/q5bjz945/2/

this is the code that I am using

```
<div class="fa-bluetooth fa-4x"></div>
```

and this is the link I am using to import font awesome

https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

any help much appreciated : )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to include font itself. This is how you should use it:

```
<div class="fa fa-bluetooth fa-4x"></div>
```

You are missing "FA" class name for your icon.